# cannot go back to terminal mode in terminal inside vim

Tags: vim, terminal

I use `:terminal` command in vim to bring terminal
And to copy texts in terminal, I exit terminal mode using `<C-\><C-n>`. But I can't go back to terminal mode again.
I tried pressing `i`, But it gives error as `modifiable is off`

How to go back to terminal mode again?

Answer (score 0):

pressing `i` will put the terminal in terminal mode, [see here](http://vimcasts.org/transcripts/74/en/). But cannot use arrow keys.

Using arrow keys will give error as `Cannot make changes 'modifiable' is off`

Answer (score 0):

Try use `:q` or `:q!` from normal mode.